# Set Enum constant values as hashmap key in java

Tags: java, enums, hashmap

I have below enum defined. I have declared a Hashmap with its key as enum. When I am trying to put enum constant value as key in hashmap, key is getting stored with "QUESTION_FIRST" while I want it to be "firstQuestion"

```
@Getter
public enum Question {

    QUESTION_FIRST("firstQuestion"),
    QUESTION_SECOND("secondQuestion");

    private final String value;

    Question(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}

public void testMethod(){
Map<Question, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(QUESTION_FIRST.getValue(), 1);
}
```

Comment: By the way, Java has a Map designed to work specifically with enum type keys. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html

Answer (score 1):

A `Map<Question, Integer>` can only have `QUESTION_FIRST` as a key.  You have three options:

- Change the `toString()` of `Question` so it prints out `"firstQuestion"`, but the actual value will still be `QUESTION_FIRST`
- Change the `Map` to a `Map<String, Integer>`, so `map.put(QUESTION_FIRST.getValue(), 1);` will work
- Give up on your desire to have `"firstQuestion"` be the key in the map.